# Fourier transforms (linked to physics)

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, physics, fourier-series, periodic-functions

I’ve been learning about Fourier series and the lecture notes I got from my maths module state (see picture attached).
However in physics I thought the harmonics were in terms of the fundamental frequency rather than the fundamental period Which are inversely related? Could anyone possibly clear this up for me? I’m struggling to get past this and it might just be a mistake?[image]

Comment: You're right.  The final highlighted sentence is incorrect.

Comment: I think you mean to say you thought that the harmonics are defined to be *multiples of* the fundamental frequency rather than *multiples of* the fundamental period. If so, then I agree. I would recommend that you ask the course instructor what exactly was supposed to be stated here.